# Remove unneeded information from bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am encountering a small problem with my thesis again. Once again I am asked to follow the academic guidelines, trying to replicate the following bibliography as close as possible

[image]

I attempted to find a style matching the picture above, but alas nothing worked. My biggest problem was two, or three parts of the bibliography

1. Finding a bibliography style which uses `1.` instead of `[1]` in the
   references.
2. Using dashed to suppress Authors with repeated entries.
3. Suppressing too much information in the bibliography.

Any ideas or help is greatly apreaciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=nature,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%
@article{Bohr1913,
    author = {Bohr, H.},
    journal = {Nachrichten von der Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Göttingen, Mathematisch-Physikalische Klasse},
    pages = {441-488},
    title = {Ueber die Bedeutung der Potenzreihen unendlich vieler Variablen in der Theorie der Dirichletschen Reihe {$\sum a_n/n^s$}},
    url = {http://eudml.org/doc/58885},
    volume = {1913},
    year = {1913},
}


@article {Hedenmalm-Lindquist-Seip,
    AUTHOR = {Hedenmalm, H\aa kan and Lindqvist, Peter and Seip, Kristian},
     TITLE = {A {H}ilbert space of {D}irichlet series and systems of dilated
              functions in {$L^2(0,1)$}},
   JOURNAL = {Duke Math. J.},
  FJOURNAL = {Duke Mathematical Journal},
    VOLUME = {86},
      YEAR = {1997},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {1--37},
      ISSN = {0012-7094},
   MRCLASS = {42B30 (30H05 46E20)},
  MRNUMBER = {1427844},
       DOI = {10.1215/S0012-7094-97-08601-4},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-97-08601-4},
}

@book {Helson-Dirichlet,
    AUTHOR = {Helson, Henry},
     TITLE = {Dirichlet series},
 PUBLISHER = {Henry Helson, Berkeley, CA},
      YEAR = {2005},
     PAGES = {loose errata+vi+91},
      ISBN = {0-9655211-6-8},
   MRCLASS = {40-02 (30B50 40A05 46J15)},
  MRNUMBER = {2116531},
MRREVIEWER = {K. Chandrasekhara Rao},
}

@article {Helson-2010,
    AUTHOR = {Helson, Henry},
     TITLE = {Hankel forms},
   JOURNAL = {Studia Math.},
  FJOURNAL = {Studia Mathematica},
    VOLUME = {198},
      YEAR = {2010},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {79--84},
      ISSN = {0039-3223},
   MRCLASS = {43A15 (15A63 47B35)},
  MRNUMBER = {2640082},
MRREVIEWER = {Fran\~A\S oise Lust-Piquard},
       DOI = {10.4064/sm198-1-5},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm198-1-5},
}

@article {Nehari,
    AUTHOR = {Nehari, Zeev},
     TITLE = {On bounded bilinear forms},
   JOURNAL = {Ann. of Math. (2)},
  FJOURNAL = {Annals of Mathematics. Second Series},
    VOLUME = {65},
      YEAR = {1957},
     PAGES = {153--162},
      ISSN = {0003-486X},
   MRCLASS = {15.0X},
  MRNUMBER = {0082945},
MRREVIEWER = {W. K. Hayman},
       DOI = {10.2307/1969670},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969670},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{Nehari}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The numeric styles don't support repeated name dashed by default. See [Make biblatex numeric style use line in bibliography entries for same author?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335960/2693).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Suppressing too much information in the bibliography".

Comment: Forget that line plase, I was quite tired when I wrote it.. What I thought was that it would be better to supress information such as "loose errata+vi+91" in the example file. However that is no longer the case =)

Comment: Please note that questions on this site normally revolve around one specific and well-defined issue. You could, for example, ask how to suppress the issue number in journal articles. What your question amounts to is finding the right style and applying all the little changes that are needed. Can you at least find a style that is sufficiently similar (you seem to have done so already) and describe *exactly* what needs to be changed with concrete examples. I'm sure if you put into words some of those requests you will be able to find previous answers on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a start

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=nyt, giveninits=true, eprint=false, url=false, doi=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%
@article{Bohr1913,
    author = {Bohr, H.},
    journal = {Nachrichten von der Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Göttingen, Mathematisch-Physikalische Klasse},
    pages = {441-488},
    title = {Ueber die Bedeutung der Potenzreihen unendlich vieler Variablen in der Theorie der Dirichletschen Reihe {$\sum a_n/n^s$}},
    url = {http://eudml.org/doc/58885},
    volume = {1913},
    year = {1913},
}


@article {Hedenmalm-Lindquist-Seip,
    AUTHOR = {Hedenmalm, H\aa kan and Lindqvist, Peter and Seip, Kristian},
     TITLE = {A {H}ilbert space of {D}irichlet series and systems of dilated
              functions in {$L^2(0,1)$}},
   JOURNAL = {Duke Math. J.},
  FJOURNAL = {Duke Mathematical Journal},
    VOLUME = {86},
      YEAR = {1997},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {1--37},
      ISSN = {0012-7094},
   MRCLASS = {42B30 (30H05 46E20)},
  MRNUMBER = {1427844},
       DOI = {10.1215/S0012-7094-97-08601-4},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-97-08601-4},
}

@book {Helson-Dirichlet,
    AUTHOR = {Helson, Henry},
     TITLE = {Dirichlet series},
 PUBLISHER = {Henry Helson, Berkeley, CA},
      YEAR = {2005},
     pagetotal = {loose errata+vi+91},
      ISBN = {0-9655211-6-8},
   MRCLASS = {40-02 (30B50 40A05 46J15)},
  MRNUMBER = {2116531},
MRREVIEWER = {K. Chandrasekhara Rao},
}

@article {Helson-2010,
    AUTHOR = {Helson, Henry},
     TITLE = {Hankel forms},
   JOURNAL = {Studia Math.},
  FJOURNAL = {Studia Mathematica},
    VOLUME = {198},
      YEAR = {2010},
    NUMBER = {1},
     PAGES = {79--84},
      ISSN = {0039-3223},
   MRCLASS = {43A15 (15A63 47B35)},
  MRNUMBER = {2640082},
MRREVIEWER = {Fran\~A\S oise Lust-Piquard},
       DOI = {10.4064/sm198-1-5},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/sm198-1-5},
}

@article {Nehari,
    AUTHOR = {Nehari, Zeev},
     TITLE = {On bounded bilinear forms},
   JOURNAL = {Ann. of Math. (2)},
  FJOURNAL = {Annals of Mathematics. Second Series},
    VOLUME = {65},
      YEAR = {1957},
     PAGES = {153--162},
      ISSN = {0003-486X},
   MRCLASS = {15.0X},
  MRNUMBER = {0082945},
MRREVIEWER = {W. K. Hayman},
       DOI = {10.2307/1969670},
       URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969670},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{pages}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\rule[.4ex]{3em}{.6pt}}

% from authortitle.bbx for the dash, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335960/
\makeatletter
\newbool{bbx@inset}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}

\renewbibmacro*{begrelated}{%
  \booltrue{bbx@inset}}

\renewbibmacro*{endrelated}{%
  \usebibmacro*{bbx:savehash}}

\InitializeBibliographyStyle{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\printtext{\bibnamedash}}
       {\printnames{author}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\printtext{\bibnamedash}}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\renewbibmacro*{translator}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translatorstrg}}
\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:translator}{translator+othersstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{bbx:translator}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifusetranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{translator}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\printtext{\bibnamedash}}
       {\printnames{translator}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{translator}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}
  \newunit}

\begin{document}

\cite{Nehari}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: example bibliography]

I used `numeric` as a base. Inspiration came from [Make biblatex numeric style use line in bibliography entries for same author?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335960/35864), and of course from [Suppress “In:” biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864)